# can't save arabic in php variable?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am really really knew to php .

I have been doing asp.net etc earlier , and this php appears a whole lot different.

I am using drupal 7 , and the project has been already made.

I was told to do something very trivial but I am unable to do so. It is regarding arabic.

I declare a simple variable like `$simpleText = "شهس "`. Then i do `drupal_set_message($simpleText)`.

What I then see on the web browser are `???` instead of the arabic . I have confirmed that the content type of the page is set to UTF-8. This is the meta tag of the rendered HTML on browser

Can you please help me identify how to eradicate this issue ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I completed many PHP projects (including Drupal projects) and there is nothing wrong with PHP and Arabic :)
add this to your HTML and it should work just fine

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

or using PHP do this before releasing any output

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Ouch . the meta tag of my html page shows exactly the tag that you have pasted :S .

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this line in connection string:

`mysql_query("set character_set_server='utf8'");`

`mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");`

Comment: thanks user254 . But I am not facing issues with regard to the mysql setup . I am just plainly in the most simplest sense , trying to print something arabic using drupal_set_message.

Answer (score 0):

You should save your file with UTF-8 encoding. If you are using Visual Studio, use "Advanced Save Options" with encoding: "Unicode (UTF-8 without signature) - Codepage 65001"